# Pesquisa de produtos com mais de uma palavra Delphi

Tags: delphi, firebird

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e gostaria de saber como faço para pesquisar um produto por mais de uma parte do nome, por exemplo:

Produto:

> Memória Ram DDR3 8Gb Notebook

Gostaria de fazer a busca digitando por exemplo: **Mem DD** ou **Mem Noteb** ou até mesmo **Mem DD Note**. 
Alguma ideia de como eu poderia fazer isso?

```
Tabela Produto
|Cod integer|
|Nome Varchar|
|Marca Varchar|
|Valor Numeric|
```

Obs: Estou utilizando o Delphi 10.2, Firebird 3.0

Comment: Coloque o código que você usa normalmente para fazer consultas por nome pois há duas maneiras de obter o resultado que você quer. Ou pelo evento `OnFilterRecord` ou pela propriedade `Filtered`.

Comment: Realmente acabei não colocando , me desculpe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Da para fazer isso somente utilizando o bom e velho SQL.
Você precisaria concatenar todos os campos que quer filtrar e colocar um alias para ele.

```
SELECT Nome+' '+Marca as campoBusca from tabela_produto
```

O retorno desse select seria:

```
         campoBusca
|Memória Ram DDR3 8Gb Notebook|
```

Daí então seria somente utilizar um where, mas como não podemos utilizar alias no where deve ser feita uma subquery, e no retorno desta utilizar o where com o perador like assim:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Nome+' '+Marca as campoBusca from tabela_produto) AS tbl
    WHERE tbl.campoBusca like '%Mem%DD%'
```

**Importante**
No campo onde o usuário vai digitar as palavras para  a busca você deve substituir os espaços por `%` e ele deve estar presete no início e fim do termpo pesquisado, assim como esta no exemplo `%Mem%DD%`, é ele quem faz a "mágica" de procurar em qualquer lugar  do campo.

Comment: Murilo, isso mesmo cara. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Se a resposta resolveu o problema, por favor marque como correta para ajudar outras pessoas que tiverem o mesmo problema.